# Why everytime I go and execute insert statements that I want to insert into a table, it says field doesn't have a default value?

Tags: mysql, schema

[Here is the screenshot of the Parts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtplT.png)

```html
INSERT INTO Supplies(Cost) 
VALUES(10.0); 

INSERT INTO Supplies(Cost) 
VALUES (20.0); 

INSERT INTO Supplies(Cost) 
VALUES (30.0); 

SELECT * FROM supplies;
```

[Here is the Supplier table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eLCt.png)

Hello Everyone,

I am working on creating a database (three tables) in MySQL and every time I run an insert statement to input a record into my Supplies table, it says 'Field Supplier_SupplierID' doesn't have a default value'. When I created my model in MySQL, I already auto-incremented 'Parts_PartID' column and that error doesn't exist anymore. So why is it doing it with 'Supplier_SupplierID' column now? Can someone please help me? Here is my model pic and sample of SQL code when I insert records into the Supplies table.

Comment: Your ID is not auto-increment. Change that

Comment: juergen d which id?

Comment: juergen d you can't have two primary keys be auto-incremented. MySQL won't allow it.

Comment: Supplier_ID has to be auto-increment. You can have one auto-increment for each table.

Comment: – juergen d I already did that. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @juergen d I meant I auto incremented for the Supplier_ID and Parts_ID primary keys.

Comment: Add the table definition to the question please. I am sure it is not set to auto-increment.

Comment: . – juergen d You can look at the embedded table definition in the link above.

Comment: That does not contain the key informations. But good luck ...

Comment: – juergen d how can i get the information then

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE supplier`

Comment: MySQL creates the table I just supply name of the table and the field names. I don't actually do all of that hard-coded coding like you probably have seen in the past.

Comment: juergen d I even try to reverse engineer my SQL script file in order to go back and make changes to the EER model. After all that, I still end up with the same error 'Field Supplier_SupplierID' doesn't have a default value'

Comment: Just execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE supplier` in your DB and it output the table definition.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert into Supplies without providing the foreign keys for the Parts table and Suppliers table.  While those primary keys in those tables may be incrementing automatically, they need to be already known when inserting into Supplies.

Typically you will use the known PartID and SupplierID that have previously been created when inserting into the Supplies table.  Those columns cannot be NULL (by definition of your table).

'Field Supplier_SupplierID' doesn't have a default value' means that you are not providing a value, there is no default value and it's not allowed to be NULL.